# Difference between redirect() and req.writehead() in Nuxt.js

Tags: redirect, nuxt.js

In Nuxt.js SSR what is the difference between `redirect(301, url)` and `req.writehead(301, { Location: url })` when using them inside `async asyncData`? As far as I can se, I get the same result with both of them when I use the following code in `/pages/folder/_.vue`.

```
export default {
  async asyncData({ redirect, req }) {
    redirect(301, url)
    // VS
    req.writehead(301, { location: url })
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @kissu, yeah it was. I was just hoping for something more in depth, but I guess the answer could be as simple as "they are the same".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect` is mainly a helper available on Nuxt's context. I didn't checked the source code but it is totally doable that it's doing the same stuff under the hood with the benefit of being easier to use/access.

There are several keys like this one in Nuxt context (like `params`): https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/context-helpers